# Cannot restart network service

Tags: linux, networking, fedora

I was trying to configure a static IP address on my Linux machine (Fedora 19 ). However when I was trying to restart my network.services using **systemctl restart network.service**, I was unable to do so.

[root@xyz network-scripts]# systemctl restart network.service 
Job failed. See system journal and 'systemctl status' for details.

I tried to reboot my system and re execute the command, but still I am getting the same error. Also I am enable to access internet on my system.

Can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: try "ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0" without quote

Comment: nope.Still unable to start services.

Comment: you used NetworkManager for setting ip? if yes then you'll have no need to restart anything. NetworkManager should take care of everything for you.

Comment: Okay, do "sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager" and "sudo systemctl enable dhcpcd" and then reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restart network services, you can use this command

```
service networking restart
```

You can also use

```
service networking stop
```

then

```
service networking start
```

Answer (score 0):

restart the **nm-applet** with this command from terminal:

```
killall nm-applet; nohup nm-applet &
```

or restart the the network manager service using:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

Restore radio frequencies by running the following command;

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

If that does not work, run this one;

```
rfkill unblock wifi
```